# Consul TLS CRL checking

Tags: consul

We're implementing consul with TLS security enabled, but it doesn't look like the consul agent performs any revocation lookup on the incoming (or local) certificates. Is this expected behavior? We'd like to be able to lock rogue/expired agents out.

Answer (score 1):

Does anything reliably implement CRL/OCSP checking? As far as I know the answer is basically no.

From what I understand, the current best practice is just to have very short-lived certs, and change them all the time.  letsencrypt is good for external services, but for internal services (which you likely use consul for), Vault(done by the same guys that do consul) has a PKI backend that does exactly this.  It publishes CRL if you have any tools that bother, but as far as I can tell, basically nothing does, because it's sort of broken (denial of service, huge CRL lists, slower, etc) More info on Vault here: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/pki/index.html

Also, there are other internal CA tools, and for larger infrastructure you could even use the letsencrypt code(it is open source).

Comment: Thanks for the info. We ended up writing our own rest service on top of openssl to be able to quickly (re)generate certs for consul. Good info about Vault, did not know it had a pki backend. That's something we'll look into.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default, Consul does not verify incoming certificates. You can enable this behavior by setting `verify_incoming` in your configuration:

```
{
  "verify_incoming": true,
  "verify_incoming_rpc": true,
  "verify_incoming_https": true,
}
```

You can also tell Consul to verify outgoing connections via TLS:

```
{
  "verify_outgoing": true,
}
```

In these situations, it may be necessary to set the `ca_file` and `ca_path` arguments as well.

Comment: Pretty sure Consul doesn't to revocation list checking even with the "verify" options turned on. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong (or behavior might have changed in newer versions, we're on 0.7.4 as far as I can remember)

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I was checking internally. You're totally correct, but this is something that is scheduled to be fixed before 1.0.