# Consul Servers with TLS enabled but not required, how to check if clients are using TLS?

Tags: consul

I'm enabling TLS connection for a Consul Datacenter with 3 servers and more than 100 node clients.
So, I config servers auto_encrypt with allow_tls as true:

```
     "ca_file": "/etc/consul/consul-agent-ca.pem",
      "cert_file": "/etc/consul/dc1-server-consul-0.pem",
      "key_file": "/etc/consul/dc1-server-consul-0-key.pem",
      "auto_encrypt": {
        "allow_tls": true
      }
```

But I did not require TLS verification, because it's a dynamic environment, I add and remove clients in daily basis. I cannot break info about node status.

```
  "verify_outgoing": false,
  "verify_server_hostname": false,
```

I need to identify which node clients are connection to the servers using TLS, and which don't.
So I can config the missing clent nodes.
I have tried a few consul commands, without success.

```
consul members
consul info
consul operator raft list-peers
```

Any tips?

Comment: I found this [Stackoverflow 41879029](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879029/consul-tls-crl-checking) , it explains how to force TLS verification, but not how to detect/show clients using TLS

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround, the service log shows the Non-TLS connection attempted

```
systemctl -l status consul
Sep 29 20:04:38 dev consul[25527]:     2021-09-29T20:04:38.280+0300 [WARN]  agent.server.rpc: Non-TLS connection attempted with VerifyIncoming set: conn=from=57.243.24.234:57367
Sep 29 20:05:35 dev consul[25527]:     2021-09-29T20:05:35.845+0300 [WARN]  agent.server.rpc: Non-TLS connection attempted with VerifyIncoming set: conn=from=127.45.234.453:60991
Sep 29 20:06:33 dev consul[25527]:     2021-09-29T20:06:33.193+0300 [WARN]  agent.server.rpc: Non-TLS connection attempted with VerifyIncoming set: conn=from=45.34.30.345:62555
Sep 29 20:07:12 dev consul[25527]:     2021-09-29T20:07:12.051+0300 [WARN]  agent.server.rpc: Non-TLS connection attempted with VerifyIncoming set: conn=from=234.45.24.345:57433
```

This is not a perfect solution, because I cannot query for TLS or Non-TLS, but it helps to check if there are clients without TLS enabled.